# How to check if tab content is loaded or not in Kendo tabstrip

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using Kendo UI for MVC. How can I check if the tab is fully loaded or not?
I want to do that to check if the user clicked on another tab before the first one is fully loaded is giving an error.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you trying to validate a tab before moving to another? Otherwise, you can hook into several [Tabstrip events](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/tabstrip#events).

Comment: Yes i want to validate if the tab which im clicking is fully loaded, then i can click the other tabs. i am asking cause im facing some error when i click and chang fast on other tabs

Comment: Validation and loading are 2 different things. So if the tab has a form on it, you would use the `select` event to validate and then either switch or stay on the current tab. Switching tabs would not normally cause errors. What error are you getting? How are you loading your content (static, ajax, etc.)?

Comment: i got this error in the console abort 0, and im loading my content with many ajax requests.

Comment: Show some code. Provide more details on whether you are hitting the server. Add some events to the Tabstrip so you can see when select, contentLoaded, etc.